# Research areas in Peano arithmetics

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory, peano-axioms, research

So I recently just finished a course on Peano arithmetics and it's non-standard models. I am very much intrigue by this topic. Hence I am rather curious what are some research areas surrounding PA right now ?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a very rich subject, but it can be hard to navigate. Rather than try to describe the subject, let me suggest a few specific sources; even if they're not quite what you're looking for, I think they'll help you get started (and their introductions and bibliographies will help you find what you do want).

- Kaye's [**Models of Peano arithmetic**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/019853213X) and Kossak/Schmerl's [**The structure of models of Peano arithmetic**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198568274) are the most obvious ones to mention. These are the only two textbooks on PA that I know of. I've listed them in chronological order, but they're both nicely self-contained; personally I prefer the latter.
- Subtheories of PA (e.g. I$\Sigma_n$) are much more easy to navigate, in my opinion. Here the book I recommend is Hajek/Pudlak's [**The metamathematics of first-order logic**](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235421926). The study of weak subtheories of PA and the study of PA itself have very different flavors, but they're both worth diving into.

---

That covers the standard texts as I see them; let me mention a couple more sources which are more difficult but which you might still find valuable.

- You specifically mentioned *models* of PA, but another very important topic here is *proof theory*. Godel's theorem says that PA cannot prove its own consistency; however, we can still ask whether we can find a "reasonably simple" system which can prove Con(PA), and in particular hope for some way of *measuring the difficulty* of proving Con(PA). The first step in this direction was taken by Gentzen, who showed roughly that the consistency of PA can be proved by a *very* weak base theory (PRA; much weaker than PA) **together with** an additional assumption: roughly that the ordinal $\epsilon_0$, which you can figuratively think of as $$\omega^{\omega^{\omega^{...}}},$$ is in fact well-ordered. That is, a certain amount of transfinite induction captures the difficulty of proving Con(PA). Moreover, Gentzen showed that no smaller ordinal would do: $\epsilon_0$ is *exactly what you need*. This was the first result in what became known as **ordinal analysis**, for which I recommend [Rathjen's survey paper](https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~rathjen/ICMend.pdf) (it quickly becomes hard going, but it should still give you enough of a taste of the subject for you to know if it's something you're interested in).
- Finally, getting back to a model-theoretic flavor, I think some of Bovykin's papers may be interesting to you, e.g. [this one](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/largeramsey/bovINTRO.pdf) or [this one](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9876/2aa21b23d7b67422fd7b6eb90cd207c94e94.pdf).