# What is the difference between "Peano arithmetic," "second-order arithmetic," and "second-order Peano arithmetic?"

Tags: logic, axioms, foundations, peano-axioms, reverse-math

I think this needs to be clarified, so it would be helpful to see an answer to this somewhere.

I've seen the following terms:

1. Peano arithmetic.
2. Second-order arithmetic.
3. Second-order Peano arithmetic.

Can anyone make a clear explanation of the difference between the three terms and what they mean?

My understanding is that (1) and (2) are theories in **first-order logic** and (3) is a theory in **second-order logic.** In particular, second-order arithmetic is a first-order theory, and it's NOT the same as second-order Peano arithmetic. Is this true?

What are the axioms for each theory? How do they differ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is basically right.

In more detail:

---

The term "Peano arithmetic" is used variously by different communities to refer to **either** *first* or *second* order Peano arithmetic (I'll denote the latter by "$\mathsf{PA}_1$" and "$\mathsf{PA}_2$" respectively). Within the modern mathematical logic community, "Peano arithmetic" almost exclusively refers to $\mathsf{PA}_1$; however, in older texts and among philosophers and historians of mathematics, it often refers to $\mathsf{PA}_2$.

The theory $\mathsf{PA}_1$ is usually formulated in the language $\{0,1,+,\times,<\}$ or something similar; roughly speaking, the only crucial point is that we have both addition and multiplication (arithmetic with only addition, for example, is [quite a different matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic)). The axioms of $\mathsf{PA}_1$ consist of:

- the *discrete positive ordered semiring* axioms (often denoted "$\mathsf{P}^-$"); and
- the *full first-order induction scheme*.

Weakening the induction scheme to apply to only certain first-order formulas results in subtheories of $\mathsf{PA}_1$; e.g. $\mathsf{I\Sigma_{17}}$ is the fragment of $\mathsf{PA_1}$ consisting of $\mathsf{P}^-$ together with induciton for $\Sigma_{17}$ formulas.

Meanwhile, $\mathsf{PA}_2$ is usually formulated in the much smaller language $\{0,\mathsf{succ}\}$ with a very sparse set of axioms ... *followed by* the full second-order induction axiom. Again, there is some flexibility in the details but the power of the underlying logic is such that it ultimately doesn't matter.

*(As an aside, if we build a direct analogue of $\mathsf{PA_1}$ with second-order logic replacing first-order logic in the setup of the induction scheme we get something appropriately equivalent to $\mathsf{PA}_2$; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/945378/what-is-an-axiom-schema/3594021#3594021).)*

---

"Second-order arithmetic" meanwhile refers to the **two-sorted, first-order** theory $\mathsf{Z_2}$. The two sorts are generally called "numbers" and "sets," and the axiom of extensionality (which is part of $\mathsf{Z_2}$) ensures that we can WLOG restrict attention to models whose sets sort literally consists of subsets of the numbers sort and whose elementhood relation is actual elementhood. The language of $\mathsf{Z_2}$ consists of the language of $\mathsf{PA}_1$ on the numbers sort, and the new binary relation "$\in$" connecting the numbers and sets sorts. Its axioms consist of:

- $\mathsf{P}^-$ for the numbers sort,
- extensionality for the sets sort, and
- the **full** induction and comprehension schemes.

Whereas the interesting subtheories of $\mathsf{PA}_1$ essentially arise from restricting the induction scheme, $\mathsf{Z_2}$ is "two-dimensional:" we get interseting subtheories by restricting **either** the induction or comprehension schemes.

---

For further reading about $\mathsf{PA}_1$ and $\mathsf{Z_2}$, and their interesting subtheories specifically, I strongly recommend [Hajek/Pudlak](https://projecteuclid.org/eBooks/perspectives-in-logic/metamathematics-of-first-order-arithmetic/toc/pl/1235421926) and [Simpson](https://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/sosoa/chapter1.pdf) respectively. See also my recommendations [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4000715/hierarchy-in-logical-systems/4000851#4000851) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2869691/research-areas-in-peano-arithmetics/2869701#2869701).